# Can I use jqueryui draggable to detect drag event on element but not move it

Tags: jquery-ui, html5-canvas

For drag on canvas mostly but also on any element. I want to detect drag event for user input but not drag things around. What is the setting to do it?

PS. I have look at a question that may seem alike. But that question is a little bit off from mine

First, I don't think that I could drag object in canvas with this function, But the drag event of jqueryui can give me a position and handle relate event, which I can use as user input to calculate my own logic

Second, that question is already 3 years without update. And it was answered by suggestion of another library. Without having exact detail about jquery ui itself

So I would like to ask again that, was jqueryui could really do it or not

Comment: You mean drag inside a canvas or dragging the canvas itself?

Comment: @TJ I already see that before post this question. Yes it is the same question but that is old without correct answer, there are talking about using other library and so on not the jqueryui itself. They not even said it is not possible for jqueryui so I'm curious

Comment: In that case you should put a bounty on old question and explain the reason in bounty notice. They refer other libraries because this is not possible with jQuery UI.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But as I see they also don't said it not possible. I will try put bounty as you suggest

Comment: Before you spent a bounty on it, read the comments on that question. It's already mentioned that it's not possible (*by a very well reputed user*). But maybe someone might alter the jQuery UI source and come up with something for bounty... who knows. But that wouldn't be *jQuery UI* as it is anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you make draggable the `canvas` html element it won't make the objects drawn in canvas draggable, only canvas element itself will drag, because everything that's being drawn on canvas is not a `html dom element` it's just a part of the raster image, so jquery ui draggable won't help you much.

if you want to have a draggable objects inside a canvas you should detect on each `mousemove` handler call wether mouse is inside an object drawn with canvas context or not and do appropriate transformations (translating in your case), or use some libraries that will do most work for you.

Comment: I know that object in canvas is not be dragged. What I ask is to detect drag event but lock the canvas to not move instead of detect `mousemove` by myself. Drag event of jqueryui is better in handle drag and touch and exit. I would use that drag event to implement my own dragging object in canvas

Comment: Why the downvote on this answer?

Comment: @Thaina  It's not possible. simple as that.

Comment: @Thaina first of draggable function underlying uses mousemove and touchmove events.  but you can just add touchmove event and do same thing as with in mousemove handler to get it work on mobile devices.

Comment: @Thaina and again you should understand what jquery ui is for. It supposed to work well only with `html dom elements` but not pixels of the raster image.

Comment: @ampawd I know it cannot drag object in canvas. I understand how canvas work. What I want to get it the drag event itself that contain the position and handle relate event like mouseup/down or gone outside of area or handle both mouse and touch at the same time. And jqueryui do a better job. So, do you understand the question?

Comment: @Thaina I don't understand your english

Comment: @ampawd OK, you know that jquery ui can add draggable, right? And it has start/drag/stop event, right? Did you know that drag event also give you drag position? Did you know you can calculate drag length with those position object?

Comment: @Thaina yes I know it gives you that information, but that's only for html elements.

Comment: @Thaina if you can't live without jquery ui, you probably can make draggable the canvas element, save it's initial position (left, top) and during the drag event just make canvas on the same place by assigning it's top and left those initial values, so canvas element will not drag. but even in this case in order to move the objects inside canvas you should do some work to check mouse is inside or not the current canvas object, then translate it etc, (actually it's simple and doesn't require much work)

Comment: @ampawd I only need to know just that information to continue implement my own work. And it not related that I could live without jqueryui or not, I just want exact information about jqueryui drag functionality. I can do a work on canvas side by myself (and already did). I just want to have a good and reliable drag event functionality that jqueryui could give me